# assign property to multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

here i want to assign four properties to a multidimentional array. 
it works if its a one-dim array by `$record.prop = "tp"`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/nr2Y9/) - this part starts from line 88

JQUERY:

```
var $record = new Array(),
    i=0,
    x,y,
    tp,rt,bt,lt;
    $record.prop = 'tp';
    $record.prop = 'rt';
    $record.prop = 'bt';
    $record.prop = 'lt';
$("td").each(function(){      
    console.log("x:"+(Math.floor(i/$cols))+",y:"+(i%$cols)); 
    x = Math.floor(i/4),
    y = i%4;
    if(!$.isArray($record[x])) { $record[x] = []; }    
    //if(!$.isArray($record[x][y])) { $record[x][y] = []; }
    if($(this).css("border-top-color") == "black"){
        $record[x][y].tp = true;
    } else { $record[x][y].tp = false; }
    if($(this).css("border-right-color") == "black"){
        $record[x][y].rt = true;
    } else { $record[x][y].rt = false; }
    if($(this).css("border-bottom-color") == "black"){
        $record[x][y].bt = true;
    } else { $record[x][y].bt = false; }
    if($(this).css("border-left-color") == "black"){
        $record[x][y].lt = true;
    } else { $record[x][y].lt = false; }
    i++;
```

});

CONSOLE ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'tp' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the `Cannot set property of undefined` error is because the sub-array is `undefined` at the time of being created.

You need to set the sub-array to an empty `object` and then assign the value like so:

```
$record[x][y] = {};
$record[x][y].tp = '...';
```

**EDIT**

Change the commented line in your code:

```
if(!$.isArray($record[x][y])){ $record[x][y] = []; }
```

to:

```
if (!$.isPlainObject($record[x][y])){ $record[x][y] = {}; }
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nr2Y9/1/).

I hope this helps!

Comment: take a look at the edited answer and see if that works.

Comment: sry it didnt work. if u can please try in jsfiddle u can come to a working solution.

Comment: No worries, if you can setup the JSFiddle and post the URL in your question, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: As requested i have added the jsfiddle in my question please check :)

Comment: You replaced the incorrect line in your code with the suggested fix. I've corrected your JSFiddle and added the link to the answer.